# Virtualhost Apache, Rails and PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache

I am trying to have a Rails application to coexist on one server along with a PHP page. I am using Apache installed through Passenger.

So, I have created a virtualhost file for my php page, and it is as such:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin mail@mail.com
ServerName subsite.site.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/subsite"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/subsite">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

My problem is that this mysite.site.com keep being redirected to the main rails site. Any idea?

Comment: Is the PHP page supposed to be accessible at mysite.site.com or subsite.site.com?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Passenger; I think you need either a different appserver, or to put the PHP app on a different subdomain.

Comment: I ended up using a totally different server (I wanted the site to be accessible through subsite.site.com)